# Error "Variable de enlace es erronea" PL-SQL ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql, trigger

!Buenas!

Realizando un ejercicio me he vuelto a encontrar un error, como de costumbre...

**Enunciado del ejercicio**:

> Y si la primera venta de un vendedor es superior a 1000€ el nombre del
>   vendedor pasará a mayúsculas

**Modelo Relacional:**

```
Clientes (id, nombre)
Vendedores (id, nombre)
Ventas (id_cliente, id_vendedor, importe, fecha)
Tabla_log(id,tipo,descripción)
Clientes_vip(id,nombre,fecha)
```

**Mi solución al ejercicio**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER primera_venta BEFORE INSERT
ON ventas
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE idVendedor integer;
BEGIN
    select id into idVendedor from vendedores where id = ventas.id_vendedor;
    if idVendedor%NOTFOUND THEN
        if :new.importe > 1000 THEN
         UPDATE vendedores set nombre = UPPER(nombre) WHERE vendedores.id = :new.id_vendedor;
         END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

**Error que me ha surgido**:

> La variable de enlace 'NEW.ID_VENDEDOR' es errónea

No entiendo muy bien el por que de este error, me refiero, **¿por que es errónea?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude resolver el ejercicio. Dejare el como ha quedado para posibles problemas de otros usuarios...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER primera_venta BEFORE INSERT
ON ventas
for each row
DECLARE
idVendedor integer;
BEGIN
select ventas.idvendedor into idVendedor from ventas where ventas.idvendedor = :new.idvendedor;
exception
when no_data_found THEN
if :new.importe > 1000 THEN
dbms_output.put_line('entra');
UPDATE vendedores set nombre = UPPER(nombre) WHERE vendedores.id = :new.idvendedor;
END IF;
END;
```

Básicamente, tenia un problema en la consulta que solucione sacando el dato de otra tabla. Y cambié el `if` por una `exception`, ya que el `if` *creo* que no puede comparar de la forma que la hacia.

En resumidas cuentas, con un par de cambios he podido solucionar el problema. Espero que esto pueda servir como ayuda a estructurar un futuro ejercicio :)